# file uploading issues in open-shift .multipart-form data in jboss7

Tags: file-upload, jboss7.x, multipartform-data, multipart, openshift

My rest method for accepting multipart-form data is not working in my openshift 
projects deployed in jboss7. 405 status code is coming but it is working fine in my 
localhost server.

```
@POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addFile(final @Context UriInfo uriInfo,@FormDataParam("file")
    InputStream uploadedFile,   @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition 
fileDetail) 
{

try {
     AddFileRequest rqst = new AddFileRequest();
     if(uploadedFile!=null){
     rqst.setUploadedFile(uploadedFile);
     rqst.setFileName(fileDetail.getFileName());}
     addFile(rqst);
     return Response.ok().build();        
 }  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();       
 }
```

Comment: The 405 code means that the HTTP method you're using isn't allowed.  Are you sending HTTP POST, or another method?

Comment: yes i am using POST method.

Comment: I would check the JBoss logs from your application and see if resteasy is complaining.